# HttpServletRequest and session associated with it

Tags: jsp, session, servlets

here is my controller class :

```
public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

    System.out.println("request in controller is " + request);
    request.setAttribute("message", "Stackoverflow");
    request.getSession().setAttribute("name", "testing");
    return new ModelAndView("test1");
```

}

test1.jsp

```
<html>
request  in test1 is <%=request%><br> 
the value of request message in test1 is      <%=request.getAttribute("message")%><br>
session value in test1 is <%=request.getSession().getAttribute("name")%>
<br><br>
<a href="test2.jsp" >next</a>
</html>
```

test2.jsp

```
<html>
request  in test2 is <%=request%><br> 
the value of request message in test2 is <%=request.getAttribute("message")%><br>
session value in test2 is <%=request.getSession().getAttribute("name")%>

</html>
```

Controller Output ::
request in controller is org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@33480f22

test1.jsp output:
request in test1 is org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest@68d91bc4
the value of request message in test1 is Stackoverflow
session value in test1 is testing

test2.jsp ouput:
request in test2 is org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@6289cd44
the value of request message in test2 is null

### session value in test2 is testing

Here my understanding is request object in all 3 cases are different.But i guess request for controller and its subsequent pass to test1.jsp is somehow related.(can somebody please explain on this)
What iam totally confused is if requests are different at least between test1 and test2 (as request attribute displayed in test1 is printed null in test2),how come session object are same between them?How two different request object gives the same session ?
My understanding is session is unique for unique request object.
Can somebody please clear my doubts on this.thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you're mistaken.

A request, as it name indicates, models a HTTP request. When the user clicks on a link, a request is sent to the server, processed by the controller and the JSP, which generate a response. Then the request vanishes.

The session exists precisely to be able to "group" all the requests coming from a given browser together. Typical use-case: you log in to the web app, store the user name in the session, and are then able to find this user name for all the subsequent requests of this user, until the session times out or is invalidated. So yes, multiple requests from the same browser do share the same session. If each request has its own session, the session would be completely useless.